# How add new fields to the existing type in another package in Golang

Tags: go

I have a custom AUTH package and there i have USER STRUCT.

So i want to import the auth package in my go project and override the struct or add new fields to the struct without modifying the package code.

```golang
package auth
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserEmail string
    UserPass  string
}
```

Now i have main.go

```golang
package main

import "auth"

// WANT TO OVERRIDE OR EXTEND THE USER STRUCT
auth.User = {
    UserAge string
}

function main() {
}
```

Comment: This is the question sir. How to make this possible. I want to import the package in the go project and override the struct defined in the package

Comment: So how to make my package flexible so anybody can import my package and add new fields without modifying the package code ? There should be some solution. Please give me some suggestion

Comment: You can define a new type in your package,  embed auth.User in it, and add any additional fields you want to add.

Comment: @bserdar But then how i will call the function like i have auth.Register(&User). How this will work ?

Comment: `auth.Register(&User.User)` If you embed auth.User without a name, then you can pass the `auth.User` part of your `User` struct to the function.

Comment: @bserdar Can you please check this example it does not seems working i just created some demo https://play.golang.org/p/Wb_OtUdTKrc

Comment: Embedding is not class inheritance. The example is working as expected. The method test() is defined on User, not UserExtended, so it'll work on the User part of UserExtended. Go is not object oriented, you have to change the way you approach your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> So i want to import the auth package in my go project and override the struct or add new fields to the struct without modifying the package code.

You simply **cannot** do this in Go. You have to redesign.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a new type like this:

```
type NewUser struct {
  auth.User
  UserAge string
}
```

Comment: Please check this example https://play.golang.org/p/Wb_OtUdTKrc
It does not seems working